# How to copy the rotation value of a sprite to a plane?

Tags: three.js

I was wondering if there is a way to copy the rotational information of a sprite into a plane. It seems that for the sprite the rotation is set within the material and it is just one value. I tried copying the matrix of the sprite into that of the plane but had no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sprite rotation is defined in WebGL as you can read in [SpritePlugin.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/webgl/plugins/SpritePlugin.js). Thus, if you wish to copy the rotation of an existing sprite in your scene, the easiest way may be to use `quaternion`. They allow better defining than x/y/z-angle defined ones (Euler rotations) as they ask for the rotation axis and the angle value. In your context, at each camera movement you modify a `quaternion`. You set it with `quaternion.setFromAxisAngle(axis,angle)`. Then apply it to the plane with `plane.setRotationFromQuaternion(quaternion)`.

Math side :

- The axis would be the cross product between the vectors lastCameraPosition-sprite.position and actualCameraPosition-sprite.position,
- the angle, the one between those vectors, got with the acos of their dot product divided by the product of their lengths.

For more about those maths, functions `getMouseProjectionOnBall` and `rotateCamera` in [TrackBallControls](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js) are of great interest.

Hope it helped !

Comment: The things is sprites in three.js always face the camera but they also allow for the sprite to be rotated around the z axis. Allowing you to spin the sprite while it still faces the camera. I want to copy the rotation information from the sprite. But I cant find where it's listed. Normal 3d objects have there quaternion information listed but sprites do not. Not that I can find at least.

Comment: what about `sprite.material.rotation` ?

Comment: sprite.material.rotation is just one value. I believe it is the z axis value. I need a way to find the x and y also.

Comment: I wish there was a way to apply the sprites rotation effect to other types of objects. There is a built in lookAt method but it does not allow for the plane to be spun. Ive been looking through the Three.js code and the lookAt method uses a matrix translation. I was trying to make a function that copys that method but does not alter the z axis. Allowing me to modify it independently but at this time martix translation are still a bit over my head.

Comment: thx for the mark. Unfortunately i dont know much about shaders but it seems those rotations are defined as one in `spritePlugin.js`. Anyway if you're interested in quaternions, the z-axis rotation would be directly dependent of the projection of `camera.up` on the plane, once the quaternion described earlier is applied. `plane.quaternion.multiplyQuaternion(z-rotation-quaternion)` to add it.